# ¿Qué significado tiene la repetición en esta frase?

Tags: gramática

Estoy leyendo el libro *Mandíbula* de Mónica Ojeda y he quedado confundido con una frase.

En el texto se lee:

> "Dr. Aguilar:
>
> Fernanda: Es que no digo que ella me odie, sino que me tiene miedo.
>
> Dr. Aguilar:
>
> Fernanda: Porque cree que soy mala. Que maté a Martín. *O que pude
> matarlo haberlo matado*, you know? Que eso pudo haber pasado"

La frase "O que pude matarlo haberlo matado" es lo que me confunde. A mí me suena como un error o quizá sea otra peculiaridad del estilo de la autora. Mi pregunta es si esto tiene algún sentido gramático o si es solo que a la autora le gusta escribir *verbatim* como si los personajes estuvieran hablando naturalmente.

Comment: Puedes poner el párrafo entero por favor, quizás tenga más sentido en contexto.

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de ser un error: la autora escribió "matarlo" y luego decidió cambiarlo a "haberlo matado" y se le olvidó borrar lo que ya estaba escrito. Pero quién sabe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La expresión en sí misma, tal y como está escrita, para mí no tiene ningún sentido.

Lo único que se me ocurre, es que haya un error tipográfico y falte una coma, y que la intención fuera escribir:

> Porque cree que soy mala. Que maté a Martín. O que pude matarlo, haberlo matado, you know? Que eso pudo haber pasado...

En este ámbito, esa pausa con la repetición del verbo cambiando el tiempo verbal, generaría énfasis en lo grave de la idea de que el personaje de Fernanda hubiera podido llegar a matar a Martín.

Answer (score 0):

Respuesta corta: no, eso no tiene sentido gramatical. Además, es estéticamente horrible. Tiene razón wimi, sin embargo yo hubiera escrito alguna de estas dos cosas:

> Porque cree que soy mala. Que maté a Martín. O que pude **matarlo habiéndolo matado**, *you know*? Que eso pudo haber pasado...

> Porque cree que soy mala. Que maté a Martín. O que pude **matarlo al haberlo matado**, *you know*? Que eso pudo haber pasado...

Lo cual hubiera hecho más interesante al texto, ya que encima que lo mató, ahora lo vuelve a matar. Interprétese esto como más plazca. No creo que sea posible ayudarte más, en todo caso tendrías que buscar otras ediciones y compararlas para ver si se trata de un error.